# Testing a sensor if it's working

Tags: sensor, thermal

How  can i test if a sensor is working ?
It's a sensor for the refrigerator.

````
(sensor's specs: 

1TW metalflex Tv 433.c 2/250 tf72°c
)
```
````

Comment: it is probably an on/off switch ... use an ohmmeter ... please post a link to the datasheet

Comment: Test it by buying a new one and see if it works.

Comment: Normally close bimetallic switch? Opens near 72’C? If really old and they oxidize, then they hi-R open, but normally never opened

Comment: Sensor is open ended, there are many sensors in a refrigerator. What is the make, model and which sensor is it. That would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a thermal cut out. They can be either switches or fuses and this seems to be a fuse. So by disconnecting the fuse and measuring with an Ohm meter you should be able to tell if its working or not. Close to zero Ohm = fuse has not blown.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer the sensor is may be part of defrosting system and disconnect the defrost heating element then the temperature reaches some point.  Just check if it is connected in series with heating element or some relay, which control heating element. Test it with conductivity tester. It is conduct at normal or low temperature and open contact at high temperature. You can heat it with heatgun, iron, etc.

Comment: The other answer says it's a thermal fuse. You could test that *once* with a heatgun, iron, etc.

Comment: @Transistor You may call it a fuse but my guess it is thermorelay. Once I fixed fridge and found out about functionality. But I could be wrong about this particular device.

Comment: It's the advert in Dejvid's answer is stating that it's a thermal fuse, not me. I don't know what it is but your answer may end up costing the OP the price of a new one.

Comment: @Transistor You mean bring the light heat may damage the device?

Comment: @Transistor it says sensor, not a fuse http://www.rdc-service.it/gb/assembled-thermalfuses/998-tf-tv-433c24.html

Comment: I can confirm it is a thermal fuse.  I blew it by putting it in hot water; previously it had a low ohm resistance, and now it's open circuit.  There must be something lost in translation on the .it site referenced above.  I has hoped it was a thermostat but I guess the 72c should have been a clue.  Anyway my freezer defroster circuit tests out OK, and yet it was still never triggering so I'm assuming it's the freezer mainboard anyway - and not something I'm going to be changing.